# What should I do for comment answer

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, accepted-answer

I asked a question: [Error libx264 not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481208/error-libx264-not-found).

And I got a comment which is good answer.

After I got the correct answer, I want to see what community thinks I should do:

- Vote up the comment only.
- Copy the comment into answer and answering my question.
- Wait for someone who will copy the comment into answer, then I accept
  it.

What to do when you have a true comment answer.

Comment: Ask the person who left the comment to put it in an answer.

Comment: @Mitch Why not copying it ? and accepting my answer.

Comment: Because technically, its not your answer.

Comment: @Mitch It is not anyone's  answer it is a comment :)

Comment: Add a comment asking [123456](http://askubuntu.com/users/224082/123456), to make it an answer.

Comment: @mitch I wont add and nice discussion

Comment: That comment answer was posted by me.

After posting the answer I went offline and returned back after around 2 hours later.

When I return all the things were happend.

My comment was helpful and there was a answer appeared based on my comment.

So posting an new answer was difficult to be done.

Comment: @123456 I mentioned your case as an example to ask community about.

Comment: @123456 And it is fine if you didn't post your comment into answer, and someone else posted it (if you mind why did't you post it)

Comment: @Mitch can I ask you to post your comment into answer? ;)

Comment: @Mitch "Because technically, its not your answer." I don't agree. All means are justified to get the best possible answer. And comments are CC also.

Answer (score 7):

Using Mitch's comment as an answer, I don't see any reason why you *shouldn't* ask the poster of the comment to post it as an answer. Only if he or she will not convert it into an answer in a reasonable amount of time, you can, for clarity reasons on a Q&A site, post it as an answer yourself. Even then I would refer to the one who answered it to start with.

There can be various reasons for someone to initially answer in a comment. To make sure the answer actually fits the question before posting it, is one of them. I don't see how posting someone else's work once the job is done serves the quality of the site, nor the willingness to answer questions.

Comment: But you actually mentioned that you used Mich's comment, why didnt ask Mitch to post it as answer instead? as you answered..

Comment: @MoathHowari That was just playing with words :). Since this is meta, there is hardly an absolute answer in situations like this, only arguments that should bring us to a commonly accepted "general idea". As such I did not copy Mitch's comment in my answer.

Comment: the only reason is that the poster didn't post the answer when he could, and as wilf comment it is free game for someone else to answer, I don't see any resason why you want the poster to answer his comment when he already didn't want to when he got chance to

Answer (score 3):

Actualy you can copy someone's comment and post it as an answer, there is no rule on Ask-Ubuntu that makes you have to tell someone to post it as an answer.

But kindly you can add a comment for him.

And what I did is I have posted that comment as an answer.

When you see comment-answer feel free  to post it as an answer.

Don't feel shy to copy a comment inside answer.

Comment: Quick note - [the guide given](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment) when you get given the privilege to comment on over people's post (when u get 50 rep) says you should avoid answering in comments.... you could of asked 123456 before posting it as answer

Comment: @Wilf No! I  don't want to ask anyone I want to answer the question,, do you mind? I have only 19 reputation points and i want to increase them..

Comment: @Wilf That is two different things. You shouldn't be *putting* answers in comments. Once there, it's free game for someone else to answer, although it is preferable that you give the original author a chance.

Comment: "although it is preferable that you give the original author a chance." It's nice to know I'm doing something right.. :-P

Comment: @ElderGeek but he already got chancE and added comment

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Jacob Vlijm. You must post a comment addressing whoever gave you the 'Comment-answer' asking them to post it as answer separately.(Better tell them that you will surely accept the answer and up vote it(and do so without fail), if they post it as an answer. Probably that will surely work! ;-D )

But then, if you commented so and even then the user who gave the comment-answer won't post it as an answer, then you must post the answer yourself. But while doing this make sure to be morally right and make it a Community Wiki. To do this while posting an answer tick the community wiki check box as shown below :

From this:

---

[image]

---

to this:

---

[image]

---

to make an answer a Community Wiki.

For example I had a similar issue(though the question was not mine in this case) [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456531/debugging-graphic-errors). Make sure to read the comments there. The OP said he will post the answer but it turns out he didn't even turn up after that. So I thought the community should know that the issue is solved and so I posted the solution there(though there is no way except for the OP to accept that answer), *as a Community Wiki*.

Comment: Damn! I forgot to deselect the CW check box! Anyways its fine. And also since its your own question here after you post the answer as CW make sure to accept it.

Comment: Good to know this is an option. Thanks @Venki

Answer (score -3):

you can add it to some useful comment's by clicking on the arrow appearing in front of the comment